# What's the recommended usage of a Git symbolic reference?

Tags: git, symbolic-references

The following shell code correctly creates a chain of symbolic references

```
git symbolic-ref "first" "refs/heads/master"
git symbolic-ref "second" "first"
git symbolic-ref "nested/third" "second"
git symbolic-ref "refs/heads/fourth" "nested/third"
```

And the following shell code correctly resolves the latest created symbolic reference to the tip of master.

```
git show-ref "refs/heads/fourth"
```

None of these use cases are described in the official documentation ([git-symbolic-ref doc](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.4.1/git-symbolic-ref.html), [git-show-ref doc](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.4.1/git-show-ref.html)).

However, the following doesn't work

```
 git check-ref-format --print "first"
```

So, my questions are:

- Is it ok to store a symbolic reference within the `refs/heads` directory ?
- Is it ok to chain symbolic references ?
- As check-ref-format fails when being passed `"first"`, does this mean that it's not recommended to create a symbolic reference at the same level than `"HEAD"`? Or maybe this command is not intended to deal with symbolic links ?

My intent is to get a clear understanding of what is being supported and that I'm not working around anything or benefiting from a bug.

Comment: While playing with this, I got `git-commit` to segfault when `HEAD` was pointing at an annotated tag.

Comment: @jleedev: This is not a bug. This a feature to prevent users from doing nasty things... :-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've eventually [posted](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/166765) this question to the git development mailing list.

[Junio C Hamano](http://www.ohloh.net/accounts/gitster), the lead git maintainer (+8700 commits) provided me with the following answers.

> There are only two valid kinds of
>   symrefs right now:
>
> - .git/HEAD, pointing at somewhere under refs/heads/ hierarchy;
> - .git/refs/remotes/{some remote name}/HEAD, pointing at somewhere
>     under   refs/remotes/{the same remote
>     name}/ hierarchy.
>
> The code may be prepared to resolve
>   recursive symrefs, symrefs other than
>   the above two kinds, symrefs that
>   point at elsewhere, but all of them
>   are outside of the design scope of
>   what the mechanism was intended to
>   support. What the code do to them
>   (without crashing) is not the design,
>   but simply an undefined behaviour.
>
> This won't change very much if we
>   decide to reorganize the remote
>   tracking hierarchies in 1.8.0.  The
>   former won't change at all, and the
>   latter will start pointing at
>   refs/remotes/{the same remote
>   name}/heads hierarchy instead.
>
> I vaguely recall tg abused the symref
>   mechanism to point .git/HEAD at funny
>   locations; it may still be doing so,
>   and if that is the case we should
>   extend the above list to cover that
>   usage.

Comment: link to said mailing list thread: http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/What-s-the-definition-of-a-valid-Git-symbolic-reference-tt6025154.html#a6026446

Comment: It's interesting, we are at version 2.28 or so, but the remote hierarchy seems to not have been changed. Maybe the idea had been dropped.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, symrefs live under `refs/` — at least, this is what the git suite does (for example when using git filter-tree, you get `refs/original/...`). Some tools may choose to ignore refs that do not have the `refs/` prefix.

```
$ git symbolic-ref refs/first refs/heads/master
$ git check-ref-format --print refs/first
refs/first
```

Comment: So, your understanding is that I'm benefiting from a loophole ? Have you got any idea about the symref chaining ? Is it valid or am I also exploiting a "non-guarded-against" usage ?

Comment: "Normally" - except for the one symref that everyone has, `HEAD`.

Comment: Refs are possible outside .git/refs/ - you can call `git log` on them - such as FETCH_HEAD, HEAD, ORIG_HEAD, RENAMED-REF. But gitk won't show them except HEAD, for example.

Comment: the git source explicitly allows chained symrefs, up to a depth of 5 (4 including `HEAD`)

Answer (score 2):

It would be desirable that symbolic links can be used more transparently and can be pushed as well.  They could be a powerful tool for new workflows.  Currently, if I create a symbolic link and then push is the server will have the hash not the link in the corresponding reference.