# Alias branch for last release in Git

Tags: git, version-control, build-automation, git-branch

We have rather common Git workflow like it's described in [this article](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).
Now on our build server we would like to make build plans for *develop*, *master* and for **the last release**. The problem is that last release branch have different names in time (*release-**).

What are the ways to solve this problem? Is it possible to create alias with permanent name *lastrelease* that can be used by a build server? Anything else?

Answer (score 2):

If you got a natural ordering rule for your release-* tags name, you can list them and pick the last one.

For instance, this can be achieved this way :

```
git tag -l release-* | sort -V
```

-l option of git tag is to list tags matching the supplied pattern.

sort -V is a special numeric sort option designed for your case

If you wanna pick the last one just append tail -1 :

```
git tag -l release-* | sort -V | tail -1
```

If you want to get the last release of a subversion (for instance 1.x releases) it's pretty easy :

```
git tag -l release-1.* | sort -V | tail -1
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create refs that point to other refs, via the `git symbolic-ref` command.

However, this isn't necessarily intended behavior: [What's the recommended usage of a Git symbolic reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986000/whats-the-recommended-usage-of-a-git-symbolic-reference)

Your other option might be to have `HEAD` of your master Git repository point at your latest `release-` branch, and then have the build server build `HEAD`, `develop`, and `master`.

A third option would be to simply have a `release-latest` branch, and use a post-receive hook to update it whenever your current `release-` branch is updated.